# how to select a section of ranges

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

To assign xx in the AP column, i have to check some fields that they must be filled before the xx assignment

i tried to assign some columns to a variable and i did the control to that variable, but it seems like it doesn't work

I got an error on this line

```
Set MaPlage = Columns("A:R" & "W:E").Rows(i)
```

this is my code :

```
Sub Decision()


Dim cell As Range

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim z As Integer
Dim u As Integer
Dim t As Integer
        Dim l As Integer
        Dim p As Integer

        Set MaPlage = Columns("A:R" & "W:E").Rows(i)

 For i = 2 To ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If CStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 31).Value) = "Completed - Appointment made / Complété - Nomination faite" And (ActiveSheet.MaPlage.Value) = "<>" Then

        If CStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 14).Value) = "AEP" _
            Or CStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 14).Value) = "CMC_REV" _
            Or CStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 14).Value) = "CMC_APT" _
            Or CStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 14).Value) = "CS_TPD" _
            Or CStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 14).Value) = "DM_ID" Then

                         ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 42).Value = "XX"
        End If


    End If

Next i
```

Comment: At the time you set maplage i=0.  i is not given a value till the for loop.  Also use `Set MaPlage = Range("A" & i & ":R" & i, "W" & i & ":E" & i)`

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks for your answer , t tried it but i still have the same error

Comment: Did you give `i` a value.  Where your line is `i = 0` and there is no row at 0.  You need to either move the statement into your loop,  or assign a value greater to 1 to `i`.

Comment: my loop should start from i= 2  right ? `For i = 2 To ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: i moved into the statement , i think that the problem is from this part `(ActiveSheet.MaPlage.Value) = "<>" `

Comment: What are you trying to do with that statement?

Comment: to check if those cells are filled or not

Comment: use this `WorksheetFunction.CountA(MaPlage) > 0`

Answer (score 0):

Combining all the comments try this:

```
For i = 2 To ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set maplage = Range("A" & i & ":H" & i & ",J" & i & ":R" & i & ",W" & i & ":Z" & i & ",AA" & i & ":AO" & i)
    If UCase(Left(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 31).Value), 3) = "COM" _
         And WorksheetFunction.Countif(MaPlage,"") = 0 Then
        Select Case UCase(Left(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 14).Value), 3)
            Case "AEP", "CMC", "CS_", "DM_"
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 42).Value = "XX"
        End Select
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks also i can return a messagebox for the cells that are not filled with ? like  this cell B must be filled

Comment: That is a new question.  Try it yourself with an if statement and cells(i,2) <> "",  Then if you cannot get it ask a new question.  Please mark as correct. @RiadhSaïd

Comment: You will need to check your spellings of all the cells.  My guess is that somewhere the spelling in the cells are different than what you have typed in the `If`` statement.  When comparing strings the way you are if the strings are not exact; Capitalization, spacing and many others, it will return false.

Comment: @RiadhSaïd  I made an edit.  I find when trying to use strings, I get the smallest part of the string(Above I use the first 3 characters) that is unique enough to test.  I also remove the issue of capitalization with ucase.  You can adjust it as you need.

Comment: the problem is that he checks all the cells all together , i need if only one cell is not filled  the xx will not be  displayed

Comment: I have changed it if any cell in the range is blank then it will return false.

Comment: Hello , i just tried it, it  doesn't work i got an error on the  UCase(Left(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 31).Value), 3)

Comment: @RiadhSaïd What error? When you get the error what is `i` and is there data in cells(i,31)?

Comment: yes :( i deleted the left and uppercase and i wrote all the string it works

Comment: yes but i have a problem with  the selection of ranges

Comment: Set MaPlage = Range("A" & i & ":H" & i, "J" & i & ":R" & i, "W" & i & ":Z" & i, "AA" & i & ":AO" & i) i got an error  wrong number of arguments

Comment: @RiadhSaïd, I have put the correct line in the code above, The commas need to be inside the quotes.

Comment: sorry to reply  late my late is very slow today , i tried but i got another error its  Run time error 1004  method range failed :/