# Selecting Multiple Ranges in Excel VBA

Tags: vba

I am trying to do affect the following cell ranges:

A - H , J - R , W - Z, and AA - AO

... using this range specification:

```
Set MaPlage = Range ("A" & i & ":H" & i, 
                     "J" & i & ":R" & i, 
                     "W" & i & ":Z" & i, 
                     "AA" & i & ":AO" & i)
```

I got the error :

```
Wrong numbers of arguments or invalid property assignment
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Clarified problem statement; formatted for easier reading; improved grammar.

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33309002/how-to-select-a-section-of-ranges/33309697?noredirect=1#comment54503426_33309697) the comma needs to be in the quotes

```
Set maplage = Range("A" & i & ":H" & i & ",J" & i & ":R" & i & ",W" & i & ":Z" & i & ",AA" & i & ":AO" & i)
```

Comment: corner i tried it it still the same Run time error 1004  : Method range failed